# How do I access the colors in the variant? in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to **loop the variant**, and also want to get data from **colors**

***i think my loop code was wrong***

```
<span v-for="{items, index} in product.variants" :key="index">
  <em v-for="(item, index) in items.colors" :key="index">{{ item.name }}</em>
</span>
```

**this is my json**

```
"variants": [
    {
     "size": "39",
     "colors": [
        {
          "name": "Red",
          "stock": 2
        },
        {
        "name": "Black",
        "stock": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
     "size": "39",
     "colors": [
        {
          "name": "Red",
          "stock": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "Black",
          "stock": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

can you help me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your product? and

Curly braces are wrong in `v-for="{items, index} in product.variants"`. It should be normal parentheses.

The following works:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-for="(items, index) in product.variants" :key="index">
    <em v-for="(item, index) in items.colors" :key="index">{{ item.name }}</em>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      product: {
        variants: [
          {
            "size": "39",
            "colors": [
              {
                "name": "Red",
                "stock": 2
              },
              {
                "name": "Black",
                "stock": 1
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "size": "39",
            "colors": [
              {
                "name": "Red",
                "stock": 2
              },
              {
                "name": "Black",
                "stock": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
<span v-for="(item1, index1) in product.variants" :key="index1">
  <em v-for="(item2, index2) in item1.colors" :key="index2">{{ item2.name }}</em>
</span>
```

Comment: 1 more thing, how to access size?

Comment: You can use `items1.size`

Comment: Thanks @Prime hope you always healthy :)

Comment: Cool, you can accept the answer so that others can find the correct answer easily.